# Существует ли точка зрения, что дату, написанную на доске, можно рассматривать как пример номинативного предложения?

Tags: синтаксис

Например, на доске написано: "2 сентября 2018 года". Таким образом, мы сообщаем, что сегодня такое-то число такого-то года. Можно ли это рассматривать как пример номинативного предложения?

Comment: Тогда уж и слово, написанное на заборе можно так же квалифицировать... Просто что-то написано, без всякого предложения (т.е. законченного высказывания)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, да. Это номинативное распространённое предложение. Названа дата.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, эту [ссылку](https://ask.fm/russian/threads/149867970876).  В Справке мне дали ответ, что этот случай нельзя считать номинативным предложением, подобные конструкции не входят в число синтаксических единиц, их статус до конца не определен. Я склоняюсь к этой точке зрения. @Людмила, Вы согласны с такими выводами?

Comment: Возможно.Статус действительно не определён. Их вообще не рассматривают. Кто-то относил их к сегментированным конструкциям, примыкающим к именительному представления. Пешковский объясняет указанную конструкцию на психологической основе, отмечая, что с ее помощью обозначаются изолированные представления предметов, и относит ее к разряду «слов и словосочетаний, не образующих ни предложений, ни их частей». Она лишь  называет предмет или явление, «представление о котором возникает в сознании говорящего», и имеет такое же строение, как номинативное предложение.

Comment: Вероятно, это действительно обозначение на уровне психики, а не синтаксиса, ведь к тексту оно не относится.

Comment: Вот в заголовок текста выносится предложение, но тоже не совсем нормальное, точка-то после него не ставится, тоже переходное явление.